# python struct disalignment windows - linux

Tags: python, linux, struct, byte

I have a working service, written in Python 3.11, that communicates with PLCs using standard sockets and ctypes for packaging / unpackaging data. This app can work both on Windows or Linux, no issue (both 64 bit).

For testing purposes, I've an additional set of scripts that can simulate different conditions with the PLC and other subsystems. One of them uses python struct to `pack` and `unpack` data, following the same protocols as the real PLC.

One of the scripts works fine in Windows, not an issue. But in Linux I find a huge difference in size of the buffer.

This is the buffer expected to be received, 5232 bytes including padding. The `@` forces padding when required.

```py
bufftype = f"@I29sLIL29sH{4*320}L4LhhIbbi"
```

(The 4 * 320 + L is intentional, it's a matrix set of 4 longs x 320 rows)

However, in Linux (Manjaro) it's failing, expecting 10384 bytes to be received, instead of 5232 bytes. If I change from `@` to standard packing with `=`, or force little endian with `<`, it will expect 5226 bytes, which is the standard size without padding for this structure.

I can't find an explanation other than, in Linux, unsigned long (L) will consume 8 bytes (instead of 4, as stated by the official doc), so 4 * 320 * 8 will fill up all that space. But then, how can I force the field type to be one that would only use 4 bytes? Any way to set this up in the interpreter so I can have a fixed behavior on this?

Comment: What stops you from setting the field to `I`? If your PLC expects a 4 byte type, that type is 4 byte on all major platforms. And `Q` is 8 byte on all plattforms

Comment: Well, thing is, PLC receives from my python app a unsigned long, not an unsigned int. The data range is not the same.

Comment: Also to mention, I find it strange that ctypes (used in the main app) manages this fine, while struct module does not. Might be it's closer to low-level. Wondering how people working on low - level system apps with python manages then these differences in type sizes....

Comment: Python uses the platform type for long. On Windows, long is always 4 byte, on Linux it is 4 or 8 byte depending on 32 vs. 64 bit platform. If you want what your C compiler on that platform thinks is `unsigned long`, use `L`. If you want a 4 byte unsigned integer, use `I`. A 4 byte `long` and a 4 byte `int` are bit-by-bit the same

Comment: @Homer512 I can live with that, you are right about the sizes. Could you please formulate it as a proper answer so I can upvote you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Windows keeps the `long` type at 4 byte on both 32 and 64 bit. Linux and Mac change it to 8 byte on 64 bit platforms.

Therefore, if the `buftype` is based on a C/C++ struct and is used to communicate with a C/C++ library, the larger buffer size is correct because that is what the C compiler for that particular platform will use.

If we are instead talking about a platform-agnostic format, like the over-the-wire protocol for network transmissions or a file format, you have to stick with a 4 byte type. `int` is 4 byte on all major platforms and if `long` is 4 byte, then `int` and `long` will be bit-by-bit the same value in memory.

See also for example

- [What is the bit size of long on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows)
- [Why is the size of a native long primitive on 64-bit Windows only 4 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446588/why-is-the-size-of-a-native-long-primitive-on-64-bit-windows-only-4-bytes)
- [Differences in Python struct module lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084379/differences-in-python-struct-module-lengths)